# Django MongoDB Queryset can't print or iterate

Tags: django, mongodb, loops, django-queryset

I try to execute a MongoDB raw query in Django of the type:

```
queryset= ObjectClass.objects(__raw__={ })
```

if I want to print the queryset or iterate I get the following error message:

```
"error_message": "cannot convert value of type <class 'mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet'> to bson",
```

Any suggestions why this happens, I couldn't find a suitable answer so far, thanks for any hints

Jonas

Comment: Are you using django-mongodb-engine with django-nonrel or what? Can you tell us the version numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just a shot into the dark since I m not able to try it out by myself in the moment, since I uninstalled mongodb. But in the back of my mind I remember that I had a similar problem.

Try:

```
queryset= list(ObjectClass.objects(__raw__={ }))
for result in queryset:
    print result
```